# Touchpad right-click doesn't work on my Asus notebook

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, asus, multi-touch

I just installed 12.04 and I noticed that my Touchpad's **right-click** isn't working at all. My Touchpad is working fine for 2 finger scrolling it also worked fine under Windows 7. The touchpad has a physical click, but I don't know if it knows the difference between left and right click.

Is there some kind of solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my HP Notebook. Try using a double tap with two fingers to right click. Worked on my Notebook when a friend suggested it to me.

Comment: Nice trick! It's working on my HP notebook as well.

Comment: why is it so? eather in other notebooks is happen.